# Writing emails is difficult vs Writing emails are difficult

Tags: nouns, gerunds, be

'Writing emails is difficult' vs 'Writing emails are difficult'.
Which one is correct? And why?

Comment: Would you say "Writing are difficult?"

Answer (score 3):

The subject of the verb is "writing emails". Gerund subjects (or infinitive subjects) are always singular so the verb is also singular.

It may also help to consider that the head of the subject is "writing" and "emails" is a complement to that. Since it is not itself the subject, its number (singular or plural) is irrelevant.

Comment: This answer is straightforward and clear. It deserves a question of substance. I never noticed gerunds are singular.

Comment: @YosefBaskin Only nouns and pronouns can be plural in English; entire clauses, both finite or nonfinite, can therefore only ever be singular: compare *To save those people’s lives ᴡᴀꜱ of paramount importance* with *Those people’s life savings ᴡᴇʀᴇ forever lost to them.* The main verb’s number can determine its governing subject head: *Children yelling obscenities in the car really ᴀɴɴᴏʏ me* means ᴄʜɪʟᴅʀᴇɴ ᴀɴɴᴏʏ, while *Children yelling obscenities in the car really ᴀɴɴᴏʏꜱ me* means ʏᴇʟʟɪɴɢ ᴀɴɴᴏʏꜱ—just like *For children to yell obscenities in the car really ᴀɴɴᴏʏꜱ me*  means ᴛᴏ ʏᴇʟʟ ᴀɴɴᴏʏꜱ.